# Renewal of Java Generic Type System

Tags: java

Is it possible that the developer of the java renew java's generic type system to make it comparable to C#'s one?

I know that the jvm has no language support for this in the class files, but is it possible to introduce such constructs afterwards into the jvm language (Class Bytecode)

Pros for better Types System in Java are:

- Fewer or No Safety Warnings at all
- Runtime Reflection for Generics
- Higher Kinded Types (HKT) would be possible

To see the last point for HKT:
Java supports Types of classes with

```
Class<T>
```

Is it also legitime to say that a class has Type

```
Class<Class<T>>
```

for instance for collections like

```
ArrayList<T>, HashSet<T>,
```

but also for some other generic classes which are not collections.
Sadly,

```
Class<Class<T>>
```

makes no sense in java because of type erasure.

Comment: Unless there are some of the Java team from Oracle out there in StackOverflow-land, you're asking the wrong people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that the developer of the java renew java's generic type system to make it comparable to C#'s one?

Is it technically possible?  If you are prepared to sacrifice backwards compatibility and render most Java code written in the last 20+ years obsolete .... yes.

Is it practical?  No.

If Oracle did this, they would destroy their Java business by alienating their customer base; i.e. thousands of organizations with I can't guess how many **billions** of dollars of sunk investment in software written Java.

And it would probably destroy their flagship database product line too, and many of their other enterprise product lines.

Then the lawsuits would start.

It would be corporate suicide.

---

It would make more sense to start again with a brand new programming language, and I can't see Oracle doing that.

Comment: 1.) Why it breaks backward compatibility and how did microsoft ruled this for C#

Comment: 2.) Why older source code cannot be recompiled with a new jvm supporting the better generic system

Comment: 1a) That is Too Broad.  1b) Microsoft C# never had the problem because they used reified generics from the beginning. 2) Because the recompiled code would behave differently.  AFAIK, there is no automatable mapping from erasure generics to reified generics that would ensure that old code still works.  If you know of one, feel free to explain ... with references / citations.